# VueJS $emit not working to push data to parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, emit

So I'm having an issue in getting `$emit` to work to send up data to the parent. What I wish to do is on click of the submit button take the data from the inputs and then send the results up to the parent. I'm using aa prototype `JSON` block just to test the flow as I'm new to Vue.

Here is some filler text as I need to get over the hump of too much code vs not enough text. Here is some filler text as I need to get over the hump of too much code vs not enough text.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined
>       at eval (SearchBar.vue?e266:42)

```
<template>
    <div class="searchbox">
         <datepicker v-model="fromdate" placeholder="Start Date" name="fromdate" class="datepicker"></datepicker>
         <datepicker v-model="todate" placeholder="End Date" name="todate" class="datepicker"></datepicker>
         <input type="text" v-model="namesearch" name="namesearch" placeholder="Username/Lastname"/>
         <input type="text" v-model="titlesearch" name="titlesearch" placeholder="Title / Short Desc."/>
         <input type="text" v-model="descsearch" name="descsearch" placeholder="Long Desc"/> 
         <button name="refreshresults" v-on:click="getresults">Do Search</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.common.js'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'SearchBar',
    components:{
     Datepicker
  },
  data(){
    return {
    fromdate:"",
    todate:"",
    namesearch:"",
    titlesearch:"",
    descsearch:""
    }
  },
  methods:{
      getresults: function(e){
        const searchcriteria = {
            fromdate: this.fromdate,
            todate: this.todate,
            namesearch: this.namesearch,
            titlesearch: this.titlesearch,
            descsearch: this.descsearch
        }
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                console.log(response.data);
                this.$emit('sendingInfo',searchcriteria);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                console.log('catchall');
            });

    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.vdp-datepicker{
    display:inline-block;
}

INPUT,BUTTON{
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `this` in your axios `.then(function() {...})` callback is not referring to your VueJS component. If you try logging `this` to console, you will see that it no longer points to your VueJS component.

Since you're using ES6, just use arrow function, so that it [preserves the lexical `this` from the enclosing scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data);
      this.$emit('sendingInfo',searchcriteria);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Terry this seems to work. I also learned I could use constant self = this; to reference this inside of the axios.

Comment: @BostonMacOSX There is really no need to create the proxy when you can use ES6 arrow function. It was created precisely to avoid unnecessary proxying.